# call a function on button click Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I am very new to Jade and NodeJS. I want to make a simple onclick function.
I searched a lot on the internet but all the solutions I found didn't work with me
I tried:

```
script.
    function clickme() {
      alert('sss')
    }

extends layout

block content
    button(onclick='clickme()')  click
```

But, when I click on the button, I get an error:

> clickme is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I also tried:

```
var clickme = function() {
      alert('sss')
    }
```

anybody can help me?

I have another question, how can I define all the functions that I need in an extra javascript file and include it in my jade code and use its functions?

Comment: You can also include any .jade/.pug file so just save your scripts in a file with that extension and include it.  I do that all the time.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your button click issue, but you should migrate to pug and get the latest feature set and bug fixes.

Comment: Aha, nice! actually it works now. I needed to call it at the end of the file, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the script inside your `block content`:

```
extends layout

block content
  button(onclick='clickme()')  click
  script.
    function clickme() {
      alert('sss')
    }
```

If you want the script in your `head` then you'd need to create another block for that in your layout.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    block head
  body
    block content
```

Then you could do this:

```
extends layout

block head
  script.
    function clickme() {
      alert('sss')
    }

block content
  button(onclick='clickme()')  click
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried it but I added at the block level not inside, which was the mistake. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, best of luck with this project.